# Prove that if $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a theorem, then $\psi \leftrightarrow \phi$ is a theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am asked to prove that the equivalence relation ~, defined as:

$$ \phi \sim \psi ~\text{if and only if} \vdash (\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)$$

have the reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties.  The reflexive property $(\phi \sim \phi)$ is just a matter of providing a derivation for the sequent $\vdash (\phi \leftrightarrow \phi)$ which is easy enough.  However, I'm not sure if my proof of the symmetric property is valid.  In the book, the definition of the symmetric property is: $$\text{If }\phi \sim \psi \text{, then }\psi \sim \phi$$

I assume that reformulating this into the language of sequents (and hence what I have to prove) is:

$$ (\vdash (\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)) \rightarrow (\vdash (\psi \leftrightarrow \phi))\tag 1$$

I have a derivation of the sequent $\{(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)\} \vdash (\psi \leftrightarrow \phi)$, and then by applying the $\rightarrow I$ rule for sequents I get

$$ \vdash ((\phi \leftrightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \leftrightarrow \phi))\tag 2 $$

1 and 2 are very similar but not identical, so I'm not sure if I need another step to get there (I can't seem to find any other rules that allow this).  Or maybe they are implicitly equivalent?  I'm not satisfied of this though, as there should be some rule of definition that explicitly states that they are the same?  Or maybe my translation of the definition of the property of symmetry is incorrect?  Any clarification would be welcome.

Comment: The formula on $(1)$ is mixing language and metalanguage. The $\vdash$ isn't part of the language. You want to prove that if $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a theorem, then $\psi \leftrightarrow \phi$ is a theorem. You've already proved that $(2)$ holds. Since $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a theorem and $((\phi \leftrightarrow \psi) \rightarrow (\psi \leftrightarrow \phi))$, using modus ponens or $\to \text{Elimination}$ or whatever you call it, you just found a proof of $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$, that is, $\phi \leftrightarrow \phi$ is a theorem.

Comment: @esotechnicha See what I did on $(2)$. I suggest you either revert it or do the same to $(1)$.

Comment: @GitGud - thanks for clearing it up.  And thanks for showing me how to number the formulae.

Comment: @GitGud Just one other question though, can the definition of the equivalence relation be written (just as correctly) as $\phi \sim \psi$ if and only if $(\phi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ without the turnstile?

Comment: Nope, not really. The sequence of symbols $\vdash \rho$ abbreviates a very specific concept, namely that there is a proof of $\rho$ from the axioms and deduction rules. Are you familiar with the double turnstile, $\vDash$? If you omit the turnstile, how will you know whether you mean $\vdash, \vDash$ or any other thing you can think of? What would simply saying "$\rho$" mean? I suppose it would mean that $\rho$ holds. But how does it hold? Truth table wise? Proof wise? And all of this is dependent on your logic system.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why it is important to distinguish between the language and the metalanguage. I think I almost see what confuses you and I think I didn't quite fill that gap completely. A more clear explanations eludes me at this point. Feel free to ask anything regarding this matter.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, hopefully it is something that will sink in the further I keep studying.  And yes I do get confused when trying to convert something from English into symbols.  So I guess the statement for symmetry would have been less confusing to me if it was something like "If we assume $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$, then a proof exists of $\psi \leftrightarrow \phi$

Comment: It should be "If we assume a proof of $\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$ exists, then a proof of $\psi\leftrightarrow\phi$ exists too". You're welcome.